# Use Wordpress Plugin without WP head

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have created a custom post template without the WP Head and footer because I don’t want to load any of the themes and plugins.

Now, I want to cache the custom post template by an SG Optimizer Plugin. How can I add the SG Optimizer to cache this custom post template?

Plugin that I want to load: https://wordpress.org/plugins/sg-cachepress/

Here's the template as follows:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Custom Post Template
 * Template Post Type: post
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <script src="another.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="some.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
Custom code
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would be a question for the developers of SG Optimiser.

Comment: You can still use `wp_head()`: remove all the default wp_head hooks - find the list in [default_filters](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L270), or there's probably a way to enumerate them too before SG Optimizer Plugin registers its hooks - and then you can call it from your template.